# Maximum and Minimum value of Quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Consider the quadratic form $Q(\vec{x})=-2x^2+2\sqrt{33}xy+6y^2$ where $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x
\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}$

It is easy to figure out the maximum and minimum value of $Q(\vec{x})$ when $\left \| \vec{x} \right \|=1$

I know how to do this, but what if $\left \| \vec{x} \right \|=5$???? then I don't know how to do it,

For example the minimum value of $Q(\vec{x})$ is $-5$ when $\left \| \vec{x} \right \|=1$, but what is the answer if $\left \| \vec{x} \right \|=5?$
Note: the correct answer is $-125$, but I have no idea why is it -125, any suggestion how to get this?

Comment: It’s homogeneous of degree $\color{blue}2$, so multiply by  $5^\color{blue}2$

Comment: I don't think that is how you do it, but thank you.

Comment: I think you are correct, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

J.W. Tanner is correct

Suppose $\vec{x}=5\vec{x}_{0}$ where $||\vec{x}_{0}||=1$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
Q(\vec{x})&=-2x^{2}+2\sqrt{33}xy+6y^{2}\\
&=-2(5x_{0})^{2}+2\sqrt{33}(5x_{0})(5y_{0})+6(y_{0})^{2}\\
&=25\left(-2x_{0}^{2}+2\sqrt{33}x_{0}y_{0}+6y_{0}^{2}\right)\\
&=25Q(\vec{x}_{0})\\
\\
\min{\left(Q(\vec{x})\right)}&=25\min{\left(Q(\vec{x}_{0})\right)}
\end{align}
$$